# SUM of values in Jquery table plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this jquery datatable [plugin](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) to display information from database. My table looks like following. Now I am trying to sum up the marks (please check the table below) and show them as total marks just like in the example given here in this [website](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function() {$('#gtable').dataTable();} );
  </script>

<table class="gtable" align="center" id="gtable">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Sl</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr><td>1</td> <td>Charlie Sheen</td>  <td>20</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td> <td>John Cryer</td>     <td>20</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td> <td>Jason Stathum</td>  <td>20</td></tr>

</tbody>

</table
```

The plugin's website have provided the following code to do and show the summation but I still don't understand how to use it my data table above.

Could you please help me with this?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
        /*
         * Calculate the total market share for all browsers in 
          this table (ie inc. outside
         * the pagination)
         */
        var iTotalMarket = 0;
        for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
        {
            iTotalMarket += aaData[i][4]*1;
        }

         /* Calculate the market share for browsers on this page */
        var iPageMarket = 0;
        for ( var i=iStart ; i<iEnd ; i++ )
        {
            iPageMarket += aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][4]*1;
        }

        /* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
        nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(iPageMarket * 100)/100 +
            '% ('+ parseInt(iTotalMarket * 100)/100 +'% total)';
     }
   } );
  } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should like this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {

    var TotalMarks = 0;
    for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
    {
        TotalMarks += aaData[i][2]*1;
    }

    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[1].innerHTML = TotalMarks;
  }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Could you please explain me what is happening with this code `aaData[i][2]*1;` what is `[2]*1;` and `nCells[1]` exactly . Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: aaData[i][2] represent the cell where "i" is for row number and 2 is representing column number. You can ignore the multiplication of 1 because it had no effect. In terms of nCell[1] its also representing the footer cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working perfectly now. But I have question, if 2 represents the column number in aaData[i][2], isn't it should be aaData[i][3] for my table as I am trying to sum of the column `<th>Marks</th>` which is column 3. But surprisingly with `2` its working perfectly. I just don't understand how? :) Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Actually it starts with the 0 index that's why your column number is 2 instead of 3.

Comment: This suggestion works perfectly but if I use the search to filter data it won't update its results... How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

very simple:

```
var sum = 0;
$("#gtable tbody tr").each(function(){
    sum += $(this).find("td").eq(3).text();
});
```

untested, tell me if you have issues.

Explanation:
What's basically going on here is that we initialize a variable 'sum' outside the scope of `$.each`, jQuery each allows you to iterate over all elements who match the condition, in this case, all the table rows in table body belonging to #gtable, than, what we do, we find the 3rd td in each row, and add it to the total sum, because JavaScript is a dynamically typed language - it is possible to do so.

now in variable 'sum' we have all the marks summation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Itai Sagi for you reply. You code is probably another way to go , but I needed to do the sum of the values using the plugin's built in function. Thanks :)